# React Native Navigation v2 increase topBar height

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

How can I increase the height of my topbar in React Native Navigation? In the styling docs, there is only an option for height in android, and this doesn't center the other things (title, buttons, etc.) in the topBar, only adding height to the bottom of the title. My current options are:

```
topBar: {
    visible: true,
    elevation: 0,
    height: 80, //Doesn't center items in topbar, only android
    title: {
       fontFamily: 'WorkSans',
       height: 80
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? You wish to have a bigger nav bar height? If so why don't you hide the nav bar and create your own custom view?

Comment: How would I make my own view? I'm new to React Native so I was trying to stick with RNN defaults

Comment: This is just one suggestion. Just tell react navigation to not give you a header. Then create a custom view and use that as your header.